# How to reload all attributes in WEKA

Tags: weka

Is there a way to reload all attributes after having removed someones without reopening the data file ?

[image]

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the screenshot, you are currently looking at the data in the preproces tab from the explorer module. In the menu above the top menu in your screenshot should be an undo option (5th option from the left).